# Create Application from Executable (and the folder it's in)

Tags: games, mint

So I was [trying out a game I heard about](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/), and the linux-compatible version of it consists of a folder of resources and one executable file. I love the game, but what's bothering me is that the way to access it is horrible. I can't seem to find a way to add it to my panel *and* give it an icon.

How can I turn this folder into an application that behaves like one from the software center? (Has a Category, Icon, etc)

**Other Info**

- I use Linux Mint, an Ubuntu fork, whereas the main difference I could find is that it uses the Cinnamon Desktop Environment.
- It looks like all the source code is in C++ at `./g_src/`, so I might be able to rebuild it.
- The file I open to start the game is a shell script that does a few commands before going to the "true" executable file.

Comment: Just create proper 'launcher' for it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: I tried to look everywhere for something like this -- how did you find it?

Comment: it's easy when you know what to look for )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ivan Temchanko](https://askubuntu.com/users/338095/ivan-temchenko) told me that I needed to create a *.desktop file, with the [tutorial found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

I will need to create the .desktop file with this in the text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=version.number
Name=Application Name
Comment=Application Description
Exec=/absolute/path/to/executable-file
Icon=/absolute/path/to/program-icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Games;Application;
```

I was able to run it as is that way, but I wanted more than that. So, I did a little more digging around.

I can use the `desktop-file-validate file` command [talked about here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/desktop-file-validate.1.html) to see if I did it right. *For some reason, I could not validate the versions "0.42.06", "42.06", "42.6" or even "42". I decided to skip this part of the desktop file.*

I then used the command `desktop-file-install file` to install the game to `/usr/share/applications/`. I could then find it in my menu, put it on a panel or move it to the desktop. This was how I wanted it, and I like it as it is this way.